# Mapping list of strings in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I want to retieve list of strings using mybatis.I am using following code ,but getting illegalArgument exception as follow :

```
   javax.servlet.ServletException: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: SqlSession operation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for java.lang.Object.toString
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
```

Mybatis configuration :

```
<select id="fetchIds" resultType="java.lang.String" >
        SELECT distinct ids 
        FROM abc.emp 
</select>
```

My Dao method is :

```
@Override
    public List<String> fetchIds() {
        System.out.println("Inside fetchIds");
        SqlSession session = null;
        List retrieveList = null;
        try{
         session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
         System.out.println("After session creation:"+session);
         retrieveList =  session.selectList("fetchIds");
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }

        return retrieveList;

    }
```

Can anybody please suggest how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Define the `List` to `List<String>`. Here your code would look like

```
<select id="fetchIds" resultType="string" >
        SELECT distinct ids 
        FROM abc.emp 
</select>
```

And Dao Method

```
@Override
    public List<String> fetchIds() {
        System.out.println("Inside fetchIds");
        SqlSession session = null;
        List<String> retrieveList = null;
        try{
         session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
         System.out.println("After session creation:"+session);
         retrieveList =  session.selectList("fetchIds");
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }

        return retrieveList;

    }
```

The mapper interface.java file has method signature as follows.

```
String[] fetchIds()throws Exception;
```

Comment: Dear Karthik,Thank you so much for your reply.I tried exactly same code that you have shared,but still I am getting same exception.

Comment: updated the answer, hope you have created the interface method signature as mentioned above

Comment: Thanks Karthik for giving your precious time.Actually it was some other code which was causing the issue.After removing that one line,my above code worked fine.Also code that you shared worked perfectly.Thanks again.